# R - Compare all values in a vector/dataframe against values in another dataframe for filtering

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

I'm new to R so I apologize for my novice question.

I have a dataframe of two variables that I have sorted to give me all my top performers in a short list. I now want to take a much larger dataframe of 4 variables, and remove all rows that do not have the performer string in the smaller list.

I have tried the following:

```
clean_df <- df[match(best$retailer, all$retailer), ]
```

But this give me a df with all my column names and NAs only.

I have also tried a few logical comparisons based on string values, but nothing has worked so far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some example?  Perhaps `df[ !all$retailer %in% best$retailer,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose if we have two dataframes ('all', 'best') and wants to keep the rows in 'all' that is not in 'best' with respect to the 'retailer' column, we can use `anti_join`.  From the output, we can check with the 'df' dataset (it is not clear though).

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(all, best, by='retailer')
```

Or may be we use `%in%` for finding the elements in 'all' that are also in 'best' for the 'retailer' column, to get the logical index and `subset` the 'df'.

```
df[all$retailer %in% best$retailer,]
```

Or using `match`, we can set `nomatch=0` so that the `NA` values that we get previously will be converted to '0'.  As indexing in R starts from 1, the 0 values have no effect in filtering.

```
df[match(best$retailer, all$retailer, nomatch=0),]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The first suggestion did not work for me as I received an error message that dplyr was not compatible with my version of R. It said it was for version 3.1.1 and I just downloaded the newest one. However the second solution worked with the removal of the "!" from the line and matched the desired result. I have not tried the second solution, but I will get that as a try as well soon.

Comment: @adlopez15  Thank you for the feedback.  You may need a new version or R for the first option to work.  But, from your comments,, looks like you need `inner_join` instead of `anti_join`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the default with `match` to be FALSE or 0, *and* also check to see that the matched index is greater than 0 so you get a logical vector that indexes correctly.

```
set.seed(0)
best <- letters[1:4]
all <- data.frame(retailer=sample(letters, 30, rep=T), x=runif(30))

all[match(all$retailer, best, 0L)>0L, ]
#    retailer         x
# 11        b 0.4112744
# 25        d 0.2447973
# 28        a 0.3162717
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked as well. I have to change the index to best$retailer as well, then I got the result I was looking for. Thanks again!